# How does the inductor have an initial condition in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, switching

If the initial current in the inductor is \$i(0^+)= 0 A \$ why is it that when the switch occurs the initial voltage in the inductor is \$ V_L(0^+)=121.4 V\$

[image: Circuit]

Comment: The voltage is there *because* of that initial current... Inductors will resist current change, but not voltage changes.

Comment: @SvenB but isn't the initial current 0 amps?

Comment: Yes, but having an initial current of 0 does not imply any initial *voltage*.

Comment: @SvenB That is what is confusing me, if the initial current is 0 amps I thought that meant it shouldn't exists an initial voltage

Comment: Then that statement is where you need some tweaking. It *only* means that there is no current through the middle branch. You'll have to find the voltages by using the other components in the circuit.

Comment: This looks like Portuguese. I do not speak Portuguese so can you translate what this says, please? I cannot simply copy and paste what it says because it's included with the picture.

Comment: @KingDuken it says that for t<0 the system has stabilized and it is in a forced regime, and that the switch from node 1 to node 2 occurs at t=0s, and to determine i(t) for t>0 S

Comment: @KingDuken Do you want to add anything?

Comment: Translation in case anybody finds it helpful:

"We consider the circuit of figure 100. We suppose that before t = 0 the switch S has been in position 1 for a long time, sufficient to allow us to consider that there has been established a forced regime(?)." (I'm going to read that as idiomatically meaning "steady state".) "At t = 0 the switch moves from position 1 to position 2. Find 'i' for t > 0: <equation for v as above>"

(Note that I speak Spanish, not Portuguese, but I think my translation should be adequate in context.)

Comment: @GlennWillen yes it is steady state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit you have is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWWyPm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have removed the component values because they are not important for this question.

ASSUMING the switch as been in position #1 to full charge the capacitor, the voltage at the capacitor is 20V

The AC voltage source follows \$ 100 \sqrt(2) Cos (100 t) \$, ie at t=0 has an instantaneous value of:  141.421V

The moment you throw the switch to connect the AC source to the RLC network you will have (141.421 - 20) 121.421 volts across the R-L, but how much across the inductor? Remember that for DC an inductor is a short circuit and for infinite frequency the inductor is open-circuit. Likewise remember on of the fundamental equations of an inductor:  \$V = L\frac{d I }{d t}\$ as a result the inductor appears as an open-circuit, initially and thus all 121.421V appears across the inductor and the inductor's current is 0

Comment: So it is because of the instantaneous change that the circuit acts as if the frequency is infinite at that instant, and because of jwL it becomes an open circuit at t=0s, correct?

Comment: exactly that. .